# automatic conversion of Text into Decimal number - Access

Tags: ms-access, data-conversion

I am trying to import data from MS SQL Server DB into MS Access using ODBC.
For mostly all datatypes the import is mapping types correctly, but when the SQL Server column datatype is Decimal Number, MS Access converts it to text datatype.
So I am trying to find a proper workaround that automatically converts this Text into Decimal Number.

E.g : 
one price is coming in as '3978.76821' and datatype is set to text so I can't run simple calculations on the field.

[image: Screenshot showing data in both SQL server and MS Access]

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17399118/edit) your question to indicate the actual mechanism are you using to import the data from SQL Server into Access. FWIW I just tested both a manual import and a `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` via ODBC and they each imported SQL Server `decimal` columns just fine.

Comment: in my case,when a decimal number with 7 decimal places on SQL Server,coming as Text in MS Access.
i am using MS Access 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access is converting the `decimal(31,7)` column to `Text(31)` because the maximum precision for an Access `Decimal` column is 28. I confirmed this by importing the following SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[importTest](
    [seq] [int] NULL,
    [textCol] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [decimalCol] [decimal](31, 7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Workaround 1:

Create a View on the SQL Server to "downsize" the offending columns...

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.importTestForAccess AS
SELECT seq, textCol, 
    CONVERT(decimal(28,7), decimalCol) AS decimalCol
FROM dbo.importTest
```

...and then import the View instead of the Table.

Workaround 2:

Import the table as before, and then convert the column from Text to Decimal in Access via VBA

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute _
        "ALTER TABLE dbo_importTest " & _
        "ALTER COLUMN decimalCol DECIMAL(28,7)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it works fine but only on the offline tables,on the other hand; when using the VBA with linked table,system is showing Run-time error "Cannot execute data definition statement on linked data source"

Comment: @AhmedAli Yes, that is true, you can't alter the "structure" of a linked table. For linking (as opposed to importing) you'll have to use "Workaround 1": create a View on the SQL Server and then link to the View instead of the Table.