# Sum function in a MS ACCESS Report is too complex

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, report

I created a report that is grouped by the seller, and I wanted to sum the field netto (which i cast as a currency in my query that the report is based on). This worked perfectly fine when i had local tables, but now I have linked tables that are connected to a SQL Server. Now all of a sudden this sum function is too complex (which surely cant be the case).

The field Netto is numeric in the DB, but when I import it, it becomes a string. Thats why i cast it to Currency in the query. I cant change the field because it tells me to change it in the DB, however it is already a number there. Does anyone know what to do?

[image]

Comment: Why is field converted to string? I have linked SQLServer tables and do not experience this. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399118/automatic-conversion-of-text-into-decimal-number-access. Perhaps try casting to different data type.

Answer (score 0):

"To complex" often means that your query has returned a Null value, and you need to exclude or convert the record.

But it is impossible to say more without seeing your SQL, sample data, and data definitions.